# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RequiredFieldValidator'.

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, foreach

I realise that there have been similar questions which can be resolved with an ID reference and .FindControl(ID) but that solution won't work for me as I am doing an iterative setting.

Situation is this. I have a 4 column table. one of which is hidden and only shown based on a date. To show the column I iterate through the table and cells making them visible. This process also needs to activate a RequiredFieldValidator that is needed for each cell if the column is shown. Here is a sample Cell from the .aspx

```
<asp:TableCell runat="server" visible="false">
<div class="pull-right form-group form-inline">
<asp:Label ID="Label28" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Sales Actual:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStationarySalesFull" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm form-control-inline-small"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator38" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="help-block" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" ValidationGroup="Form" ControlToValidate="txtStationarySalesFull" Enabled="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
</asp:TableCell>
```

To achieve this I was trying:

```
foreach (TableRow row in tblGoals.Rows)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                cell.Visible = true;

                foreach (RequiredFieldValidator fv in cell.Controls)
                {
                    fv.Enabled = true;
                }
            }

        }
```

This doesn't work though. It will find the controls collection fine, but of the 5 controls returned there are no RequiredFieldValidators in the collection and it fails out with :

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RequiredFieldValidator'.

The controls collection contains two LiteralControls, a TextBox and two Text values. Weirdly the second text="" is actually the requiredfieldvalidator I am looking for.

Any ideas how I can actually make this work? I would rather like to avoid referencing each control by ID as this is mostly going to be reused code.

I can think of a messy version involving

```
foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                cell.Visible = true;
                if (cell.Controls.Count > 4) {
                    RequiredFieldValidator fv = (RequiredFieldValidator)cell.Controls[3];
                    fv.Enabled = true;
                }

            }
```

But that doesn't catch all cases. There are some cells where there are less controls that need the validator enabled.

Comment: `cell.Controls.OfType<RequiredFieldValidator>`

Comment: Oh God! My brain really must not be working today!!!!!!! Thanks

Comment: `cell.Controls.OfType` will not work, will it?  You have to address the controls inside the div that is inside the cell.  Right?

Comment: And since you know that the required validator is the third inside that cell, why use Linq and not just address it directly... `cell.Controls[0].Controls[2]`

Comment: five controls inside the table cell?  Isn't it one div inside the table cell and then three controls inside the div?

Comment: When you ran the code as was the collection was count 5

Comment: A div is a control as far as cell.Controls is concerned. It's just a LiteralControl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq, ever to the rescue.  `cell.Controls.OfType<RequiredFieldValidator>` should return all controls in that collection that are of type `RequiredFieldValidator`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Will's answer, your loop could become like this:

```
foreach (TableRow row in tblGoals.Rows)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                cell.Visible = true;

                foreach (RequiredFieldValidator fv in cell.Controls.OfType<RequiredFieldValidator>)
                {
                    fv.Enabled = true;
                }
            }

        }
```

In the third `foreach` loop, you have to filter only controls of type `RequiredFieldValidator`

Comment: This is exactly what I changed it to :)